# Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of ..., boolean given, called in ... on line ... and defined in ... on line

Tags: php, arguments, boolean

I have added a CMS to my server. I am just wondering why I keep getting this error on a Page to purchase a subscription.

This is the error;

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to ObjectArray::fromMySQLiResult() must be an instance of
mysqli_result, boolean given, called in
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\model\FactoryObjects\User.php on line 71
and defined in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\lib\ObjectArray.php on line 284
```

Line 71 has the following;

```
public function getOrders() {
    $objectArray = new ObjectArray();
    $result = $this->getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM vip_orders WHERE user_id =
    '" . $this->id. "'");
    $objectArray->fromMySQLiResult($result); (<Line 71<)
    return $objectArray;
}
```

Line 284 has the following;

```
public function fromMySQLiResult(mysqli_result $result) (<Line 284<)
{
    $this->clear();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $this->add($row);   
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Please let me know if any other information is necessary for you to help me fix this error!

Thanks!

(Note: For those assisting, could you please explain what exactly is the problem? For example, what the function is and why it is not working, thank you.)

Comment: That gives me Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\model\FactoryObjects\User.php on line 71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of `fromMySQLiResult(mysqli_result $result)` states that the function requires a parameter of type `mysqli_result`. However, you are passing the result of [mysqli::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) which might also be of type boolean in case of failure.

To prevent the error, make sure `$result` is actually a query result similar to the example in the documentation:

```
if ($result) {
    $objectArray->fromMySQLiResult($result);
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: So, should I edit this function? public function fromMySQLiResult(mysqli_result $result)
 {
  $this->clear();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
  {
   $this->add($row); 
  }
  return $this;
 }

Comment: No, just surround the call of `$objectArray->fromMySQLiResult($result)` as shown to handle errors.